# How do I get a specific data from an array using pdo

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

This is a result array from a php pdo query.

How can I get e.g. only the `sitetitle` which has `langCode` 'en'?

```
Array
( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [alias] => home [sitetitle] => LALALA [langCode] => de [langName] => Deutsch ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [alias] => home [sitetitle] => LOLOLO [langCode] => en [langName] => English ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [alias] => home [sitetitle] => LELELE [langCode] => es [langName] => EspaÃ±ol )
)
```

Comment: what about seting some where condition in the query.

Comment: @V-X i need the other data on another point

Comment: You need a query to get sitetitle wich has langCode = en or based on your result, you need extract sitetitle of that array?

Comment: i want to store the result in an array beacuse i need the other data for other issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will iterate the array, find the first element with langCode =='en' and return the sitetitle of it. If no elements have langCode =='en', it will return an empty string.

```
function getEngSiteTitle($arr){
    for each($arr as $v)
        if($v['langCode']=='en')return($v['siteTitle']);
    return('');
}
```